# How to pass data from html page to another using angular and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

---

Here is mine controller:

```
app.controller('UserListCtrl', function($scope, UsersResource){
    $scope.users = UsersResource.query();
});
```

This is my page (written in Jade)

```
li(ng-repeat="user in users")
  a.button(href='/user/{{ user.id }}') View Profile
```

The problem is that I want to have for each user unique id without having to declare it in database (MongoDB) and when I click on that user , I want it to be passed on the next page (/user/uniqueId) and show information about the user (user.firstName and user.lastName)

Answer (score -1):

Before some days I had the same problem, I read some where that angular is basically for Single Page Applications.

I used templates to overcome that problem.

[This Page](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.in/2013/03/TemplatesRoutingAndSharingDataBetweenViewsInAnAngularJsApplication.html) talks about how to use this.

I have given my [github](https://github.com/surajbabar/UNO) reference, the one which I solved.

cheers
All the best